# allowed File locations under Android 11

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I encounter a problem, since i want to recompile my App for the new Android 11 and above. And i think the core problem i have is with this scoped storage.
Is there any List of allowed Filepaths where i can still read/write as i want or do i really have to integrate this MediaAccess API?

My Filepath to go would be as follows:

```
    public static string XmlFilename = "Arbeitszeiten.xml";
    public static string filepath = "/storage/emulated/0/Documents/Arbeitszeiten";
```

Until Android 10 it worked fine, since i want to save/edit/read a .xml file on the Device itself i need a "allowed" filepath. I thought that Scoped Storage blocks the Access to the /Android/data and ../obb folder. And that the Downloads, Pictures, Documents are Folders still accessible.

Comment: Can you explain what are you trying to achieve so it would be easier for me to guide you onto the current path as of now all i understand from the question is that do you really need to integrate the media access api and the short answer to it is yes

Comment: Well your file path is ok. Use it. Why didnt you already?

Comment: Hey @FreakyAli thanks for your comment! I already updated, and hopefully precised, my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What helped me was to adapt my minimum Version to Android 10 API 29 and the Target Version to Android 11 API 30 in the Manifest. Since i didn't found the android:requestLegacyExternalStorage Permission i think it's only a temporary solution, but for now it works.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a problem looks like yours on Android 11 in kotlin.
I solved it like this:

1. I added file_path.xml in path src/main/res/xml

   [FilePath](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AzLWU.png)
2. I've used **getExternalFilesDir** for get file in the device storage.

Before:

```
val mPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/Ticket_" + date + ".jpeg"
```

After:

```
 val mPath = context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).toString() + "/Ticket_" + date + ".jpeg"
```

I hope help you :)